# Formatting numbers with commas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can someone help format this script? I'm not sure why it's not formatting correctly. It should be formatting thousands with commas (i.e: 1000>1,000) but nothing I do seems to work. :c

I've tried adding codes that replace numbers and everything, but due to the nature of how numbers are generated with this script, I'm guessing I'm missing something obvious that's preventing formatting from happening?

```js
var xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
  select = function(s) {
    return document.querySelector(s);
  },
  selectAll = function(s) {
    return document.querySelectorAll(s);
  },
  container = select('.container'),
  dragger = select('#dragger'),
  dragVal,
  maxDrag = 300

//center the container cos it's pretty an' that
TweenMax.set(container, {
  position: 'absolute',
  top: '0%',
  left: '0%',
  xPercent: 0,
  yPercent: 0
})
TweenMax.set('svg', {
  visibility: 'visible'
})

TweenMax.set('#upText', {
  alpha: 0,
  transformOrigin: '50% 50%'
})

TweenLite.defaultEase = Elastic.easeOut.config(0.4, 0.1);

var tl = new TimelineMax({
  paused: true
});
tl.addLabel("blobUp")
  .to('#display', 1, {
    attr: {
      cy: '-=40',
      r: 30
    }
  })
  .to('#dragger', 1, {
    attr: {
      //cy:'-=2',
      r: 8
    }
  }, '-=1')
  .set('#dragger', {
    strokeWidth: 4
  }, '-=1')
  .to('.downText', 1, {
    //alpha:0,
    alpha: 0,
    transformOrigin: '50% 50%'
  }, '-=1')
  .to('.upText', 1, {
    //alpha:1,
    alpha: 1,
    transformOrigin: '50% 50%'
  }, '-=1')
  .addPause()
  .addLabel("blobDown")
  .to('#display', 1, {
    attr: {
      cy: 299.5,
      r: 0
    },
    ease: Expo.easeOut
  })
  .to('#dragger', 1, {
    attr: {
      //cy:'-=35',
      r: 13
    }
  }, '-=1')
  .set('#dragger', {
    strokeWidth: 0
  }, '-=1')
  .to('.downText', 1, {
    alpha: 1,
    ease: Power4.easeOut
  }, '-=1')
  .to('.upText', 0.2, {
    alpha: 0,
    ease: Power4.easeOut,
    attr: {
      y: '+=45'
    }
  }, '-=1')

Draggable.create(dragger, {
  type: 'x',
  cursor: 'pointer',
  throwProps: true,
  bounds: {
    minX: 0,
    maxX: maxDrag
  },
  onPress: function() {

    tl.play('blobUp')
  },
  onRelease: function() {
    tl.play('blobDown')
  },
  onDrag: dragUpdate,
  onThrowUpdate: dragUpdate
})

function dragUpdate() {
  dragVal = Math.round((this.target._gsTransform.x / maxDrag) * 1000);
  select('.downText').textContent = select('.upText').textContent = dragVal;
  
  var a = document.getElementsByClassName('downText')[0].innerHTML;
document.getElementsByClassName('perYear')[0].innerHTML = parseInt(dragVal*18.4);
var b = document.getElementsByClassName('downText')[0].innerHTML;
document.getElementsByClassName('perTwentyFive')[0].innerHTML = parseInt(a*460);
var c = document.getElementsByClassName('downText')[0].innerHTML;
document.getElementsByClassName('perMonthCoal')[0].innerHTML = parseInt(a*1);
var d = document.getElementsByClassName('downText')[0].innerHTML;
document.getElementsByClassName('perMonthSolar')[0].innerHTML = parseInt(a*0.79);
  
 
  TweenMax.to('#display', 1.3, {
    x: this.target._gsTransform.x

  })

  TweenMax.staggerTo(['.upText', '.downText'], 1, {
    // x:this.target._gsTransform.x,
    cycle: {
      attr: [{
        x: this.target._gsTransform.x + 146
      }]
    },
    ease: Elastic.easeOut.config(1, 0.4)
  }, '0.02')
}

TweenMax.to(dragger, 1, {
  x: 30,
  onUpdate: dragUpdate,
  ease: Power1.easeInOut
})



var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'USD',
  minimumFractionDigits: 0,
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.upText,
.downText {
  text-anchor: middle;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 172px;
  fill: #ffffff;
  color: black;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  pointer-events: none;
  text-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
margin-left: 10px;
margin-top: 0px;
line-height: 140px;
}

.upText {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-family: IntCircular-Medium;
  letter-spacing: -0.5px;
}

#dragger{
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0); 
}

.downText {
  letter-spacing: -0.4px;
  font-family: IntCircular-Thin;
}
```

```html
<div class="downText" id="downText">100</div>

<div class="container">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="100 222 400 250">
  <defs>
    <filter id="goo" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="8" result="blur"/>
      <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 21 -7" result="cm"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <g id="dragGroup">
    <path id="dragBar" fill="#ff9600" d="M447 299.5c0 1.4-1.1 2.5-2.5 2.5h-296c-1.4 0-2.5-1.1-2.5-2.5l0 0c0-1.4 1.1-2.5 2.5-2.5h296C445.9 297 447 298.1 447 299.5L447 299.5z"/>
    <g id="displayGroup">
      <g id="gooGroup" filter="url(#goo)">
        <circle id="display" fill="#ffab18" cx="146" cy="299.5" r="13"/>
        <circle id="dragger" fill="#ffab18" stroke="#ff6600" stroke-width="0" cx="146" cy="299.5" r="13"/>
      </g>
      <text class="upText" x="145" y="266"/>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>


</div>

<div class="perYear" id="perYear"></div> The div id above is "perYear" and its number is formed by taking the contents of the div "downText" and multiplying by 18.4<br><br>
<div class="perTwentyFive" id="perTwentyFive"></div> The div id above is "perTwentyFive" and its number is formed by taking the contents of the div "downText" and multiplying by 460<br><br>
<div class="perMonthCoal" id="perMonthCoal"></div> The div id above is "perMonthCoal" and its number is formed by taking the contents of the div "downText" and multiplying by 1<br><br>
<div class="perMonthSolar" id="perMonthSolar"></div> The div id above is "perMonthSolar" and its number  is formed by taking the contents of the div "downText" and multiplying by 0.79

<script src='http://vibralifeusa.com/slider-test/1.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='http://vibralifeusa.com/slider-test/2.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

Comment: That's a whole lot of code for just formatting 1000->1,000.  Can you reduce it to just the problem?  Have a look here:  [mcve]

Comment: The code is a slider I'm using on my website. The only part of the code that's actually attempting to format anything is this part: 

var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'USD',
  minimumFractionDigits: 0,
});

Comment: The slider updates the numbers as you drag it, but I need the numbers to be formatted also, and I'm not sure how to do it or where to place the formatting code.

Comment: Try using `var units = 1000;` and then getting it to print `1,000`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved you `formatter` variable to the top, and then initializing it at every calculation.

`ex: formatter.format(dragVal * 18.4);`

> Se the documentation for [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat)

```js
var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'USD',
  maximumSignificantDigits: 0,
});

var xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
  select = function(s) {
    return document.querySelector(s);
  },
  selectAll = function(s) {
    return document.querySelectorAll(s);
  },
  container = select('.container'),
  dragger = select('#dragger'),
  dragVal,
  maxDrag = 300

//center the container cos it's pretty an' that
TweenMax.set(container, {
  position: 'absolute',
  top: '0%',
  left: '0%',
  xPercent: 0,
  yPercent: 0
})
TweenMax.set('svg', {
  visibility: 'visible'
})

TweenMax.set('#upText', {
  alpha: 0,
  transformOrigin: '50% 50%'
})

TweenLite.defaultEase = Elastic.easeOut.config(0.4, 0.1);

var tl = new TimelineMax({
  paused: true
});
tl.addLabel("blobUp")
  .to('#display', 1, {
    attr: {
      cy: '-=40',
      r: 30
    }
  })
  .to('#dragger', 1, {
    attr: {
      //cy:'-=2',
      r: 8
    }
  }, '-=1')
  .set('#dragger', {
    strokeWidth: 4
  }, '-=1')
  .to('.downText', 1, {
    //alpha:0,
    alpha: 0,
    transformOrigin: '50% 50%'
  }, '-=1')
  .to('.upText', 1, {
    //alpha:1,
    alpha: 1,
    transformOrigin: '50% 50%'
  }, '-=1')
  .addPause()
  .addLabel("blobDown")
  .to('#display', 1, {
    attr: {
      cy: 299.5,
      r: 0
    },
    ease: Expo.easeOut
  })
  .to('#dragger', 1, {
    attr: {
      //cy:'-=35',
      r: 13
    }
  }, '-=1')
  .set('#dragger', {
    strokeWidth: 0
  }, '-=1')
  .to('.downText', 1, {
    alpha: 1,
    ease: Power4.easeOut
  }, '-=1')
  .to('.upText', 0.2, {
    alpha: 0,
    ease: Power4.easeOut,
    attr: {
      y: '+=45'
    }
  }, '-=1')

Draggable.create(dragger, {
  type: 'x',
  cursor: 'pointer',
  throwProps: true,
  bounds: {
    minX: 0,
    maxX: maxDrag
  },
  onPress: function() {

    tl.play('blobUp')
  },
  onRelease: function() {
    tl.play('blobDown')
  },
  onDrag: dragUpdate,
  onThrowUpdate: dragUpdate
})

function dragUpdate() {
  dragVal = Math.round((this.target._gsTransform.x / maxDrag) * 1000);
  select('.downText').textContent = select('.upText').textContent = dragVal;
  var a = document.getElementsByClassName('downText')[0].innerHTML;
document.getElementsByClassName('perYear')[0].innerHTML = formatter.format(dragVal*18.4);
var b = document.getElementsByClassName('downText')[0].innerHTML;
document.getElementsByClassName('perTwentyFive')[0].innerHTML = formatter.format(a*460);
var c = document.getElementsByClassName('downText')[0].innerHTML;
document.getElementsByClassName('perMonthCoal')[0].innerHTML = formatter.format(a*1);
var d = document.getElementsByClassName('downText')[0].innerHTML;
document.getElementsByClassName('perMonthSolar')[0].innerHTML = formatter.format(a*0.79);
  
 
  TweenMax.to('#display', 1.3, {
    x: this.target._gsTransform.x

  })

  TweenMax.staggerTo(['.upText', '.downText'], 1, {
    // x:this.target._gsTransform.x,
    cycle: {
      attr: [{
        x: this.target._gsTransform.x + 146
      }]
    },
    ease: Elastic.easeOut.config(1, 0.4)
  }, '0.02')
}

TweenMax.to(dragger, 1, {
  x: 30,
  onUpdate: dragUpdate,
  ease: Power1.easeInOut
})
```

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.upText,
.downText {
  text-anchor: middle;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 172px;
  fill: #ffffff;
  color: black;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  pointer-events: none;
  text-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
margin-left: 10px;
margin-top: 0px;
line-height: 140px;
}

.upText {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-family: IntCircular-Medium;
  letter-spacing: -0.5px;
}

#dragger{
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0); 
}

.downText {
  letter-spacing: -0.4px;
  font-family: IntCircular-Thin;
}
```

```html
<div class="downText" id="downText">100</div>

<div class="container">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="100 222 400 250">
  <defs>
    <filter id="goo" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="8" result="blur"/>
      <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 21 -7" result="cm"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <g id="dragGroup">
    <path id="dragBar" fill="#ff9600" d="M447 299.5c0 1.4-1.1 2.5-2.5 2.5h-296c-1.4 0-2.5-1.1-2.5-2.5l0 0c0-1.4 1.1-2.5 2.5-2.5h296C445.9 297 447 298.1 447 299.5L447 299.5z"/>
    <g id="displayGroup">
      <g id="gooGroup" filter="url(#goo)">
        <circle id="display" fill="#ffab18" cx="146" cy="299.5" r="13"/>
        <circle id="dragger" fill="#ffab18" stroke="#ff6600" stroke-width="0" cx="146" cy="299.5" r="13"/>
      </g>
      <text class="upText" x="145" y="266"/>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>


</div>

<div class="perYear" id="perYear"></div> The div id above is "perYear" and its number is formed by taking the contents of the div "downText" and multiplying by 18.4<br><br>
<div class="perTwentyFive" id="perTwentyFive"></div> The div id above is "perTwentyFive" and its number is formed by taking the contents of the div "downText" and multiplying by 460<br><br>
<div class="perMonthCoal" id="perMonthCoal"></div> The div id above is "perMonthCoal" and its number is formed by taking the contents of the div "downText" and multiplying by 1<br><br>
<div class="perMonthSolar" id="perMonthSolar"></div> The div id above is "perMonthSolar" and its number  is formed by taking the contents of the div "downText" and multiplying by 0.79

<script src='http://vibralifeusa.com/slider-test/1.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='http://vibralifeusa.com/slider-test/2.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

Comment: One of the numbers was rounding incorrectly, but otherwise this is exactly what I needed! Thank you so much, Zorken!

Comment: You are welcome. I have also updated the code so you can use your `formatter` variable.